# Inheritance in spring batch not working as intended

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-batch

When I run the following code using spring batch I get an exception.

```
<job id="simpleJob">
  <step id="parentStep">
    <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
      <chunk reader="simpleReader" writer="simpleWriter" commit-interval="3"/>
    </tasklet>
  </step>
   <step id="concreteStep1" parent="parentStep">
    <tasklet start-limit="5">
       <chunk processor="simpleProcessor" commit-interval="2"/>
    </tasklet>
  </step>
</job>
```

It gives the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The element [concreteStep1] is unreachable
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I have seen similar code in the [spring source](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#InheritingFromParentStep). Even this does not work. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent step should be out of  scope. That is:

```
<job id="simpleJob">
   <step id="concreteStep1" parent="parentStep">
    <tasklet start-limit="5">
       <chunk processor="simpleProcessor" commit-interval="2"/>
    </tasklet>
  </step>
</job>
<step id="parentStep">
  <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
    <chunk reader="simpleReader" writer="simpleWriter" commit-interval="3"/>
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

Comment: hi Serkan , thanks for the help ... It worked perfectly ... I had one more doubt ... Can i have something like the following code ??

Comment: <job id="simpleJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
   <step id="concreteStep1" parent="parentStep1">
    <tasklet start-limit="5">
       <chunk processor="simpleProcessor" commit-interval="2"/>
    </tasklet>
  </step>
</job>
<step id="parentStep1" parent="parentStep">
  <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
    <chunk writer="simpleWriter" commit-interval="3"/>
  </tasklet>
</step>
<step id="parentStep">
  <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
    <chunk reader="simpleReader" commit-interval="3"/>
  </tasklet>
</step>`

Comment: A step in Spring Batch combines a reader and a writer. If you divide them in two different steps (a step for reading and a step for writing) then you are assuming that developer will be responsible for data exchange between these two steps.
If your reader and writer is related and they do operate on the same  chunks, then I would suggest not impleting this kind of configuration.